Where is Kernel Fleck from?
The second book of the Demonata series, Demon Thief, introduces the main viewpoint character of Kernel Fleck. Where in the world is he from? We know that Grubbs and Bec are both from (very different historical eras of) Ireland, and indeed are very distantly related to each other through the werewolf family, but the description of Kernel's village feels very culturally different - it's been many years since I read the book, but I remember wondering if it might have been in Africa.
